# apply strings as variable names in bind_rows

Tags: r, dplyr

The names of the dataframes below can easily be recreated with paste, but the result cannot be fed into bind_rows.

Here are consistently named dataframes (x1, x2, x3):

```r
library(dplyr)

x1 <- tibble(col1 = state.abb[1:3])
x2 <- tibble(col1 = state.abb[4:6])
x3 <- tibble(col1 = state.abb[7:9])
```

bind_rows works....but typing each name is tedious

```r
bind_rows(x1,x2,x3)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 1
#>   col1 
#>   <chr>
#> 1 AL   
#> 2 AK   
#> 3 AZ   
#> 4 AR   
#> 5 CA   
#> 6 CO   
#> 7 CT   
#> 8 DE   
#> 9 FL
```

I would like to create the names with paste, or some comparably simple way

```r
created.names <- paste0("x", 1:3)
[1] "x1" "x2" "x3"

bind_rows(created.names)
#> Error in bind_rows_(x, .id): Argument 1 must have names
```

Created on 2018-07-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mget` on the names before `bind_rows`, which returns a list of data frames with the names provided:

```
bind_rows(mget(created.names))

# A tibble: 9 x 1
#  col1 
#  <chr>
#1 AL   
#2 AK   
#3 AZ   
#4 AR   
#5 CA   
#6 CO   
#7 CT   
#8 DE   
#9 FL
```