# Problems quoting and unquoting strings with bind_rows() inside a function

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a little function to write out a table of proportions from a  set questionnaire items, which are ordered factors. I do `table()` for each item, convert them to data frames, and make them wide. I then intend to put them together in one table. 
Here's what the output for this example should look like:

```
                  item not enough just right   too much
1 nl_netops_groupcom_1  0.2692308  0.6923077 0.03846154
2 nl_netops_groupcom_2  0.2000000  0.8000000 0.00000000
3 nl_netops_groupcom_3  0.4166667  0.5833333 0.00000000
```

But when I try to `bind_rows()` the data frames, it seems that the data frame objects can't be found. Here is the code of the function:

```r
make.freq.tab <- function(df.name=df_tp1, ...) {

    the.vars <- df_tp1 %>% select(...) %>% colnames()
    for(the.var in the.vars) {
         the.tab <- as.data.frame(table(df.name[, the.var])) %>%
             mutate(pcp=Freq / sum(Freq)) %>%
             select(-Freq) %>%
             spread(key=Var1, value=pcp) %>%
             mutate(item=the.var) %>%
             as.data.frame(.)

         assign(the.var, the.tab[, c(4, 1, 2, 3)])
    }

    return(bind_rows(syms(the.vars)))
}
```

But when I run it, like this:

```
make.freq.tab(df_tp1, nl_netops_groupcom_1:nl_netops_groupcom_3)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : object 'nl_netops_groupcom_1' not found
```

Am I confusing the language processor because I'm using `the.var` as both a character variable and a data frame name? I'd really like to do it this way, because using the `the.vars` as the string of column names and also as the names of the data frames to bind together is very convenient. 
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput(df_tp1)` ?

Comment: Your question sounds somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51162948/apply-strings-as-variable-names-in-bind-rows), where `mget()` turned out to be useful.  It also seems like saving the datasets into a list to bind rather than assigning would be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @aosmith's `mget` suggestion, here's a `purrr` solution (since you are working in the tidyverse idiom--also, note that you want to revise the first reference to `df_tp1` in your function to `df.frame`, since that's the argument):

```
make.freq.tab <- function(df.name=df_tp1, ...) {

  the.vars <- df.name %>% select(...) %>% colnames()

  the.tab <- map(the.vars, ~ as.data.frame(table(df.name[, .x])) %>%
                   mutate(pcp=Freq / sum(Freq)) %>%
                   select(-Freq) %>%
                   spread(key=Var1, value=pcp) %>%
                   mutate(item=.x) %>%
                   as.data.frame(.) %>% 
                   select(4, 1, 2, 3)
                 )

  return(bind_rows(the.tab))
}
```

@aosmith's suggestion:

```
make.freq.tab <- function(df.name=df_tp1, ...) {

    the.vars <- df.name %>% select(...) %>% colnames()
    for(the.var in the.vars) {
         the.tab <- as.data.frame(table(df.name[, the.var])) %>%
             mutate(pcp=Freq / sum(Freq)) %>%
             select(-Freq) %>%
             spread(key=Var1, value=pcp) %>%
             mutate(item=the.var) %>%
             as.data.frame(.)

         assign(the.var, the.tab[, c(4, 1, 2, 3)])
    }

    return(bind_rows(mget({{the.vars}})))
}
```